# PHP log file parse by regex

Tags: php, regex

I have parsed logs from a log file using php and I have pushed these lines in an array.

```
[2020-01-21 18:01:23] local.INFO: Backup success
[2020-01-21 18:11:03] local.DEBUG: aid=1 bac=2343
[2020-01-21 18:21:29] production.CRITICAL:send failed
[2020-01-21 18:51:01] production.WARNING:limit 7/9 reached
```

from each line how I can get my expected output more efficiently?

```
$final = [];
foreach($lines as $line){
    //best way to parse data to $date, $env, $type, $message from $line variable?

    $arr = [
        'date'=> $date,
        'env'=> $env,
        'type'=> $type,
        'message'=> $message
    ];
    array_push($final, $arr);
}
```

Expectation

```
[
    {
        "date":"2020-01-21 18:01:23",
        "env":"local",
        "type":"INFO",
        "message":"Backup success"
    },
    {
        "date":"2020-01-21 18:21:29",
        "env":"production",
        "type":"CRITICAL",
        "message":"send failed"
    },
    ...
    ...
]
```

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! have you tried any regex? if so, what regex have you tried?

Comment: Some hints to avoid using REGEXP: Explode by spaces. Remove brackets from first element to get date and time, explode second element by dot to get env and type, implode by spaces last elements to get the message. Maybe explode by : to get message first, and then other elements.

Comment: this one has space `local.INFO: Backup success` but this one has no space `production.CRITICAL:send failed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this version.

```php
$re = '/^\[(?<date>.*)\]\s(?<env>\w+)\.(?<type>\w+):(?<message>.*)/m';

$str = '[2020-01-21 18:01:23] local.INFO: Backup success
[2020-01-21 18:11:03] local.DEBUG: aid=1 bac=2343
[2020-01-21 18:21:29] production.CRITICAL:send failed
[2020-01-21 18:51:01] production.WARNING:limit 7/9 reached';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);

// Print json string
echo json_encode($matches, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this resolves your answer to the question :)

```
$lines = '[2020-01-21 18:01:23] local.INFO: Backup success';
$arr = explode('] ', $lines);
$arr1 = explode(': ', $arr[1]);
$arr2 = explode('.', $arr1[0]);
$arr[0] = str_replace("[","",$arr[0]);
echo 'date = ' . $arr[0];
echo '<br>';
echo 'env = ' .$arr2[0];
echo '<br>';
echo 'type = ' .$arr2[1];
echo '<br>';
echo 'message = ' .$arr1[1];
echo '<br>';
```

Comment: Look at line 3,4 in logs. no space between log type and log info. already tried. `$info = explode(': ', $line);
            $temp = explode('] ', $info[0]);
            $temp2 = explode('.', $temp[1]);` please see the logs lines carefully. I am looking for error risk free solution with regex

Answer (score 0):

Mix of explodes, substrings, trim and array destructuring:

```
$final = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    [$envType, $message] = explode(':', substr($line, 22));
    [$env, $type] = explode('.', $envType);

    $final[] = [
        'date'    => substr($line, 1, 19),
        'env'     => $env,
        'type'    => $type,
        'message' => trim($message)
    ];
}

$jsonFormat = json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```